# python-requests library throws error in https connection

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

In my production server suddenly python-requests library throws this error on making https connection with 3rd party application.

> raised unexpected: SSLError(SSLError(SSLError("bad ca_certs: '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cacert.pem'", Error([('system library', 'fopen', 'No such file or directory'), ('BIO routines', 'BIO_new_file', 'no such file'), ('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load_cert_crl_file', 'system lib')],)),),)

please suggest some solutions and reason behind this exception.

Edit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/vogo/api/api/api/celery.py", line 146, in spreadsheets_management
    ss          = gs.open_by_key("10K_0JGCVZjngWo7dr1CTeRJ1rAhMWxAGxHbl_NworeU")
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 105, in open_by_key
    feed = self.get_spreadsheets_feed()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 155, in get_spreadsheets_feed
    r = self.session.get(url)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 73, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 65, in request
    response = func(url, data=data, params=params, headers=request_headers, files=files, json=json)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    """
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    :param allow_redirects: (optional) Set to True by default.
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send

  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
```

python version: 2.7.6

python-requests version: 2.18.4

Edit: My Code

```
def request(self, method, url, data=None, params=None, headers=None, files=None, json=None):
        if data and isinstance(data, bytes):
            data = data.decode()

        if data and not isinstance(data, basestring):
            data = urlencode(data)

        if data is not None:
            data = data.encode('utf8')

        # If we have data and Content-Type is not set, set it...
        if data and not headers.get('Content-Type', None):
            headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

        request_headers = self.headers.copy()

        if headers:
            for k, v in headers.items():
                if v is None:
                    del request_headers[k]
                else:
                    request_headers[k] = v

        try:
            # self.requests_session = requests.Session() // this is init. before
            func = getattr(self.requests_session, method.lower())
        except AttributeError:
            raise RequestError("HTTP method '{}' is not supported".format(method))

        response = func(url, data=data, params=params, headers=request_headers, files=files, json=json)

        if response.status_code > 399:
            raise RequestError(response.status_code, "{0}: {1}".format(
                response.status_code, response.content))
        return response
```

Comment: Also write the requests library version and python version you are using.

Comment: The error message says clearly that it cannot access `/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cacert.pem`. Since this happened suddenly - maybe somebody has tampered with the environment and removed this file or changed permissions.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich once i restarted my instance it worked again, my  application system is running with two instances, i have restarted one instance and it started working and other instance keeps on throwing error same error.